# sql to linq in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have to convert it to Linq in vb.net. I am new to sql to linq. Guidance welcomed

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a.StartDt,112) datenew,
COUNT(distinct(b.EmployerAccountOid)) companymoved, 
COUNT(distinct(c.EmployerAccountOid)) companyfailed,
COUNT(distinct(d.ProductAccountOid)) planmoved,
COUNT(distinct(e.ProductAccountOid)) planfailed
from ebp.MgnCOREDCDataGroupMigrationRun a
left join ebp.MgnCOREDCMigrationRun b
on a.MigrationRunID = b.MigrationRunID
And TypeCd = 1 and a.MigrationStatusCd = 4
left join ebp.MgnCOREDCMigrationRun c
on a.MigrationRunID = c.MigrationRunID
and TypeCd = 1 and a.MigrationStatusCd = 5
left join ebp.MgnCOREDCMigrationRun d
on a.MigrationRunID = d.MigrationRunID
and TypeCd = 2 and a.MigrationStatusCd = 4
left join ebp.MgnCOREDCMigrationRun e
on a.MigrationRunID = e.MigrationRunID
and TypeCd = 2 and a.MigrationStatusCd = 5
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a.StartDt,112)
```

I tried to convert it to Linq with fail.

```
Dim query1= (From migrationgroup In UnitOfWork.DbContext.Set( Of MgnCOREDCDataGroupMigrationRun)()
 Group Join migration In UnitOfWork.Set(of MgnCOREDCMigrationRun)() On migrationgroup.MigrationRunID Equals migration.MigrationRunID And migrationgroup.TypeCode = 1 And migrationgroup.MigrationStatusCode=4 _
 Into migrationErrorGrp = Group 
 From mgeg In migrationErrorGrp.DefaultIfEmpty()
 Group Join migration1 In UnitOfWork.Set(of MgnCOREDCMigrationRun)() On migration1.MigrationRunID Equals migrationgroup.MigrationRunID And migrationgroup.TypeCode = 1 And migrationgroup.MigrationStatusCode=4 _
 Into migrationErrorGrp1 = Group 
 From mgeg1 In migrationErrorGrp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
 Group Join migration2 In UnitOfWork.Set(of MgnCOREDCMigrationRun)() On migration2.MigrationRunID Equals migrationgroup.MigrationRunID And migrationgroup.TypeCode = 2 And migrationgroup.MigrationStatusCode=5 _
 Into migrationErrorGrp2 = Group 
 From mgeg2 In migrationErrorGrp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
 Group Join migration3 In UnitOfWork.Set(of MgnCOREDCMigrationRun)() On migration3.MigrationRunID Equals migrationgroup.MigrationRunID And migrationgroup.TypeCode = 2 And migrationgroup.MigrationStatusCode=5 _
 Into migrationErrorGrp3 = Group 
 From mgeg3 In migrationErrorGrp3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                Group By  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),migrationgroup.StartDt,112) into g
select New With{CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),migrationgroup.StartDt,112), 
                Count(distinct(migration.EmployerAccountOid)) , 
                Count(distinct(migration1.EmployerAccountOid)), 
                Count(distinct(migration2.EmployerAccountOid)), 
                Count(distinct(migration3.EmployerAccountOid))}).ToList()

                If IsNothing(query1) Then
                    Return Nothing
                    End If
                coredcmigrationhistory =
                    From coredcmigrationrow In query1()
```

My query is non-queryable. Can anybody guide me where I m goin wrong

Comment: It looks like you are mixing SQL in with the LINQ code.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin I dont know how to express the select statement in linq

Comment: Instead of `CONVERT` to varchar, why don't you just use `.ToString`?